# get Java byte[] from HashMap<String , byte>

Tags: java

I have a

```
Map nameANDbytes =  new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
```

How can I get that byte array out of map?

Lets say I put

```
 InputStream input = zipfile.getInputStream(zipentry);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
 nameANDbytes.put(fileName, br.toString().getBytes());
```

print is :

```
*.png
[B@1339e7aa
```

now I want to get values :

```
byte[] b = entry.getValue().toString().getBytes();
```

and it is

```
[B@1fb669c3
```

What's wrong?

Comment: _What's wrong_ Although not completely clear from your question, I would say the `br.toString().getBytes()` is wrong. `br.toString()` does not read your input. You are just getting a String representation of the `BufferedReader` and then you convert that string to a byte array. Perfectly valid code, but probably not what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
byte[] b = (byte[]) entry.getValue();
```